# need to include a prepopulated coredata compatible sqlite db with app: here is my strategy How to implement?

Tags: iphone, macos, sqlite, core-data

So after doing a LOT of research on the web. I figured the best way to ship my app is to ship it with a sqlite db that is generated by coredata application.

Now to go about it I have decide that the following needs to be done:
1) Convert the data into a CSV format
2) Create a Coredata Mac application on my desktop
3) Parse the csv file and feed the contents to the coredata application on my mac and save as sqlite db.
4) Since the coredata model on the mac and iPhone is the same the underlying sqlite db will be  compatible.
5) Include the sqlite db that was generated by my mac app with the iphone app.

So the question then is:

To create a mac app where do I start?
So far these are the steps I can think of:
1) Create a Mac app in XCode with Core data
2) create the "schema" on the coredata model that maps to the CSV file data
--??? This is where i get stuck!!
What next ??
Can someone help me please?
I cannot find any resources on the web for this or Im searching with the wrong keywords

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the exact same thing you wanted except I created a second target in my iPhone app that parses the csv and writes it out to core data. Run it in the simulator, you can find the sqlite file in 
/"home"/Libary/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/"the app"/Documents

This way everything is kept in one project.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing. I generated the CoreData db in the app with an #ifdef section that generated the db. That seemed simpler than creating a separate Mac application.

If you need to change the CoreData db in the app just copy it to the Library or Documents directory on initial startup. The only gotcha was that I had to change the db extension in the app so that Xcode would not make changes during compile/archive.